# Touchpad ALPS problem with two fingers right click, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, dell, multi-touch

Guys!

I have very strange problem with ALPS touchpad (DELL Latitude E7470 laptop) on Ubuntu 16.04 (the same issue on 16.10, but not on Mint Cin 18.3): when I try to produce right click on touchpad (ALPS) via two finger gesture I have real right click only with probability about 1/4. With probability 3/4 I haven't one (with the same initial conditions). To be honest, I can produce right click only after two times two finger gesture. I have read related topics and FAQs but my experiments with tuning parameters doesn't solve a problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using libinput or xorg-synaptics?

Comment: Pilot6, I have both libinput and xorg-input-synaptics installed on a system, but in Xorg.0.log I see only the following:
"LoadModule: "synaptics""

Comment: Load path/synaptics_drv.so
And after that -- synaptics driver will be used for device "AlpsPS/2 DualPoint Touchpad"
I haven't any information in a log about libinput...

Answer (score 0):

Install libinput by

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

and reboot. It supports multitouch better. Tap-to click will be disabled by default, but it can be enabled.

Comment: Thank you, Pilot6. I have installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput package, learn tutorial from many sources. But my touchpad have the same problem -- sometimes two finger tap work, but sometimes cursor only move after two finger tap... It's a pity :(( I believe , hardware is ok, bcof under win and mint all work correctly...

Comment: This must be a kernel issue.

Comment: Well, what do you recommend - should I update kernel or use another distro? Is it good (?) practise to update kernel in LTS?

Comment: It is not a good to install unsupported kernels, but you can try to install 4.11 and test.